# Password Reset policy in OpenSSO

Tags: smtp, hmac, opensso, hmacsha1, opends

I had to implement Password Reset policy....For which I had OpenSSO deployed on Glassfish server and OpenDS as the Data Store...I followed Indira's blog...

[Password Reset With OpenDS](http://blogs.oracle.com/indira/entry/password_reset_with_opends)

And executed all commands....Since I did not configure SMTP, when I try to Reset the Password of a particular User (Note: I hav specified a Gmail ID as the email Address of that user) after answering the Question, I get confirmation saying

"Your password has been reset but we are unable to send it to you. Contact your administrator."

How do I configure SMTP in OpenSSO and OpenDS?

Answer (score 1):

OpenDS (and OpenDJ, the continuing open source project) has some global properties to point to the SMTP server.
Note that it doesn't support authentication at this point.

$ dsconfig set-global-configuration-prop --port 4444 --hostname `hostname` --bindDN "cn=Directory Manager" --bindPassword password --set smtp-server:smtp.example.com --trustAll --no-prompt

Kind regards,

Ludovic

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem, so for the record I think it's probably because you need to replace `<Password-Administrator>` in the WEB-INF/classes/amPasswordResetModuleMsgs*.properties files with a real email address.

I found that my *Authentication* debug log file had this error in it:

```
ERROR: Could not send email to user [Ljava.lang.String;@30720e48
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 5.5.4 <Password-Administrator>... Domain name required for sender address Password-Administrator
;
  nested exception is:
        com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 553 5.5.4 <Password-Administrator>... Domain name required for sender address Password-Administrator

        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)
```

I found the solution on the OpenAM mailing list originally: http://lists.forgerock.org/pipermail/openam/2012-April/005912.html

I used this sed command to do update all the files at once:

```
sed -i -e 's/\<Password-Administrator\>/user@address\.com\.au/g' amPasswordResetModuleMsgs*.properties
```